# Tax percent in invoice

Tags: invoice, tax

I want to display the tax percent in invoice **without** decimal. Now my invoice display:

```
Tax (21.0000%):
```

How can I put that without decimal? 21%

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Magento 1 I believe this may have to do with what's done in
`app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Totals.php`:

```
public function formatValue($total)
{
    if (!$total->getIsFormated()) {
        return $this->getOrder()->formatPrice($total->getValue());
    }
    return $total->getValue();
}
```

But modifying this should also have impact on the other places the taxes are displayed (such as cart and checkout) so be careful with that.